# Configure TFS deploy test agent URI

Tags: tfs

In a TFS release definition I've got a Deploy TestAgent task that has installed a test agent remotely on a test machine but then can't get a connection back to the local TFS server.

I think that's because of the initialize job environment variables like:

`[SYSTEM_TASKDEFINITIONSURI] --> [http://mypc:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/]
 [SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI] --> [http://mypc:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/]
 [SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI] --> [http://mypc:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/]`

when `mypc` actually needs to be an IP address of the machine hosting TFS server. How can I set these variables so the test agent can connect to the TFS server?!

The test agent deployment then has a configuration for the `TfsCollection` as `(http://mypc:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/)` and so the remote test agent gets the error:

`Unable to connect to Team Foundation Server, Check if TFS is reachable from the test agent.`

`System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "One or more errors occurred." ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'mypc'`

Comment: Have you deployed the TestAgent successfully? or the error appears during the Test Agent deployment? Make sure you match the [Demands and prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/test/visual-studio-test-agent-deployment?view=vsts#demands-and-prerequisites)

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT yes it deploys, the problem is it then doesn't recognise the path from the remote machine to the TFS server `The remote name could not be resolved` so I want to know how to set the remote name. Do I need a Test Settings file or something?

Comment: How did you deploy the Test Agent? what about using the IP instead of the machine name? Just have a try for that.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT yes the Test Agent is deployed using the Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment task and to the IP for the target machine. The trouble is after the Test Agent is installed on the target machine (successfully) it tries to connect back to the TFS server (on another machine) but gets the errors above. I can't seem to set the TFS server IP ??

Comment: Sounds like an network issue, can you ping the TFS server from the Test agent machine?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT well that's just it, yes I can ping the external IP and there can be a route to the TFS server - but I cannot ping `mypc:8080` which is where the Test Agent thinks the TFS server is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is Test Agent machine cannot reach TFS server. It should be an network issue.

Just check the route or firewall settings to make sure the connectivity between TFS Server and Test agent machine is OK. Then try it again.

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on rupweb's comments below, the solution is to add an entry in the `etc/hosts` file to map `mypc` and the TFS server `IP`:

Just add the following entry `1.2.3.4 mypc` to `etc/hosts` at `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` and then the remote Test Agent can reach the TFS server via it's IP rather than DNS.

Comment: Aha, so a solution is to add an entry in the etc/hosts file to map `mypc` and the TFS server IP...

Comment: yes you need to add the following entry `1.2.3.4        mypc` to `etc/hosts` at `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` and then the remote Test Agent can reach the TFS server via it's IP rather than DNS

Comment: @rupweb Thanks for the sharing, I also updated the answer with your 
 solution, you could accept it as an answer, this can be beneficial to others who read this thread :)